# Word-break \ Word-wrap CSS issues in HTML email

Tags: html, css, office365, dynamics-365

So we're using Dynamics 365 Marketing for our email marketing platform.
In house we use Office 365 & alot of our customers also use it (as we market to Corporate businesses).  Oh, and the OS on our machines is Win10.

Something has changed (either with D365 or Office 365) over the Easter break;
While in the HTML i have always had `word-break: normal; word-wrap: normal` on `<td>` tags - we come back from easter and suddenly headings in the email render like this (in office 365).

[image]

If i view the email in the browser then word-break isn't happening (and it looks like this) & at the same time if i view the email in Outlook 2016 (on Win10) the word-break's are also not appearing.
[image]

Does anyone know if MS\Outlook has its own styling for word-breaks?

Or anyone have any suggestions?

this give's an idea of the code for the banner;

i know this is a rather abstract question... ive just got the marketing dept & exec's getting pissy with me as i don't have an explanation for what's going on.

```css
p {
  word-break: normal;
  word-wrap: normal;
}

td {
  word-break: normal;
  word-wrap: normal;
}

div {
  word-break: normal;
  word-wrap: normal;
}
```

```html
<td style="vertical-align: middle; text-align: left;" valign="middle" align="left">
  <table style="float:none;width:100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="center">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td style="height:26px;line-height:26px" valign="top" height="26" align="left">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="banner-text-1 bannerLargeColor" style="font-size: 12px; line-height: 12px; font-weight: 700; letter-spacing: 4px; vertical-align: top; text-align: left;" valign="top" align="left">
          <!--<div data-sub-block="true" data-block-datatype="Text"><p style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; mso-line-height-rule: at-least;"><span style="font-size:12px;"><strong>MEMBERSHIP</strong></span></p></div>-->
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="height:9px;line-height:9px" valign="top" height="9" align="left">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="banner-text-2" style="font-size: 24px; line-height: 23px; color: #fff; font-weight: 700; letter-spacing: 4px; vertical-align: top; text-align: left;" valign="top" align="left">
          <div data-sub-block="true" data-block-datatype="Text">
            <p style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; word-break: normal; font-size:24px;"><strong>THANK YOU FOR ATTENDING 2023 INFRASTRUCTURE CONFERENCE</strong></p>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="height:26px;line-height:26px" valign="top" height="26" align="left">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</td>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using "mso-hyphenate: none" That removed the word breaks for me.

Comment: Thanks Lisa! :-)  My guess is a Word 365 update removed support for `word-break`.  Its like we're dealing with Internet Explorer all over again.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a fix yet, but I also noticed this problem on April 10. We don't use Dynamics 365 Marketing, but someone on my team who has Windows Outlook pointed out the problem when I sent a test that day. My code doesn't specify any word-break or word-wrap behavior, but I've never had an issue until now.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: If your marketing emails are being received on devices running Windows & using Outlook, then you'll want to use MS specific CSS (cause why would MS use a standard).
But yeah the solution listed below to use `mso-hyphenate: none` solved my issue.